# Mysql index not working

Tags: mysql

Have the following table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `PARSER_U_R_L` (
  `PARSER_ID` varchar(20) COLLATE latin1_general_cs NOT NULL,
  `URL_MD5` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_cs NOT NULL,
  `ENTRY_POINT_ID` varchar(20) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `TYPE_ID` varchar(20) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `STATUS_ID` varchar(20) COLLATE latin1_general_cs DEFAULT NULL,
  `INDEXED_TIME` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`PARSER_ID`,`URL_MD5`),
  KEY `PURL_PARSER` (`PARSER_ID`))
 ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_cs;
```

As you see PRIMARY KEY in the Parser_id and URL_MD5.
When I try a simple select

```
EXPLAIN 
    SELECT   * 
    FROM  `PARSER_U_R_L` 
    WHERE `URL_MD5` IN ( ids )
```

In EXPLAIN of this select I have possible keys = Null.

What can be problem ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `URL_MD5` is not the *first* column in your primary key.  Since you have an index with multiple columns, the optimizer won't use that index unless you supply a value for the first column as well.

If you supply a value for *just* the first column, the optimizer will use it, 
so try reversing the columns in the index.